# Why does $\bigcup_{X \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})}X = \mathbb{N}$, instead of $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a practice problem I just came across,
$$\bigcup_{X \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})}X =$$
I came up with $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$, but the book lists $\mathbb{N}$ as the solution. I would've thought the solution set would look something like this,
$$\{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{309,12\},\{14,900,8,22\},\{6\},... \}$$
as opposed to this,
$$\{ 1,2,3,...812,...973,... \}$$
We're "unionizing" every possible element of $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$, each of which is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, *not* an *element* of $\mathbb{N}$. More generally, if for set $S$ you were to take the union of all it's elements, wouldn't your result be set $S$ itself?
$$\bigcup_{x \in S}x=S$$
Not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any help most welcome :)

Update: I get it now. Thanks for you helpful explanations. My mistake was, as Brian put it,

> When you take a union of sets, you’re collecting the elements of those sets into one bit set; you’re not collecting the sets themselves.

So my "general" example of taking the union of all the elements in a set is wrong because you can't take the union of elements, only the union of sets. **I blame it all on the curly brackets** :)

Comment: You are right .

Comment: I don't agree with the statement "my 'general' example of taking the union of all the elements in a set is wrong because you can't take the union of elements, only the union of sets." Even if $S$ is a set of sets (and in axiomatic set theory everything is a set) the union $\bigcup_{x\in S}x$ (which by the way can be written more simply as $\bigcup S$) is not generally the same thing as $S$ itself.

Comment: You're right to blame it on the curly brackets though.  To go from $S$ to $\bigcup S$ you essentially "remove some curly brackets" as in Brian's example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What does it mean to say that $$x\in\bigcup_{X\in\wp(\Bbb N)}X\;?$$ By definition it means that there is some $X\in\wp(\Bbb N)$ such that $x\in X$. In other words, there is some $X\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $x\in X$. But then $x\in X\subseteq\Bbb N$, so $x\in\Bbb N$. In other words, every member of $\bigcup_{X\in\wp(\Bbb N)}X$ is a natural number, and

$$\bigcup_{X\in\wp(\Bbb N)}X\subseteq\Bbb N\;.$$

Note too that if $x\in X\in\wp(\Bbb N)$, then by definition $x\in\bigcup_{X\in\wp(\Bbb N)}X$, so for every $X\in\wp(\Bbb N)$ we have $X\subseteq\bigcup_{X\in\wp(\Bbb N)}X$. In particular, for any $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $\{n\}\in\wp(\Bbb N)$, so $n\in\{n\}\subseteq\bigcup_{X\in\wp(\Bbb N)}X$, and therefore $$\Bbb N\subseteq\bigcup_{X\in\wp(\Bbb N)}X\;.$$ It follows immediately that $$\bigcup_{X\in\wp(\Bbb N)}X=\Bbb N\;.$$

It may help to look at a finite example. What is $$\bigcup_{X\in\wp(S)}X\;,$$ where $S=\{0,1,2\}$? $\wp(S)=\big\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\}.\{2\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\}\big\}$, so $$\bigcup_{X\in\wp(S)}X=\varnothing\cup\{0\}\cup\{1\}\cup\{2\}\cup\{0,1\}\cup\{0,2\}\cup\{1,2\}\cup\{0,1,2\}=\{0,1,2\}=S\;.$$

When you take a union of sets, you’re collecting the **elements** of those sets into one big set; you’re not collecting the sets themselves.

Comment: @ivan: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 5):

If $X\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N) $, then $X \subseteq \mathbb N$. So the union of two $X,Y\in\mathcal P (\mathbb N)$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$.

Your second remark is (depending on notation) wrong. $\bigcup\limits_{x\in S} x$ is not defined if the element of S are not sets themselves. One way to circumvent this is to identify $x$ with $\{x\}$ in such a union, so the union becomes $$\bigcup\limits_{x\in S} x = \bigcup\limits_{\{x\}\subseteq S} \{x\}$$

Comment: @Stephan - Ah, I see your point. I was totally misinterpreting the union operation in this example.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the symbol is
$$
\bigcup_{X \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})}X = \{ x : \text{$x \in X$ for some $X \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$} \}.
$$
So this union is a subset of $\Bbb{N}$ (which takes care of any worry we might have because I have written $\{ x : \dots \}$ without specifying an ambient set), because $x \in X \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is just a convoluted way to say $x \in \Bbb{N}$. And clearly, given any $x \in \Bbb{N}$, then $x \in \{ x \} \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Answer (score 3):

Every element $X \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ satisfies $X \subset \mathbb{N}$, so you must have $\cup_{X \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})} X \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3):

The ***union*** of sets combines all ***elements*** of those sets, which results in ***one*** *set* containing *every element* that belongs to *any of the sets we are taking the union*.

So are taking the union of all $X_i \in \mathcal{P}$ which is the set $$\bigcup_{X \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})}X = \bigcup_{X_i \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})}X_i \; =\{x \in X_1 \lor x \in X_2, \lor ...X_n \lor x\in \ldots \mid X_i \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)\} $$
$$ = \{x \in X_i \mid X_i \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N), \;\;\text{for some}\;\;i\in I\}= \mathbb N$$

Answer (score 2):

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a collection of sets, and $B$ is such that for all $i\in I$, $A_i\subseteq B$. Then $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\subseteq B$.

*Proof.* Let $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ then there exists some $i\in I$ such that $x\in A_i$. We assumed that $A_i\subseteq B$, and therefore $x\in B$. $\square$

Therefore $\bigcup_{X\in\mathcal P(A)}X\subseteq A$. The other direction is obvious because $A\in\mathcal P(A)$ so it is a part of this union. Now apply this for $A=\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\cup_{a\in \cal A}a$, where $\cal A$ is a collection of subsets of a set $X$, is the set consisting of all elements who are in some set of $\cal A$.
More precisely, $\cup_{a\in \cal A}a=\{x\in X:\exists a\in \cal A,\, x\in a\}$.
You can't do $\cup_{x\in S}x$ unless you can join (who is an operation of sets) the elements of $S$.